# How to downsize a cv2 program?

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller

Below is a very simple python program.

```
import os
from cv2 import VideoCapture

print("hello")
```

But after I convert it to exe(by pyinstaller),
the size of this exe file is very big (~150MB).

I know the root cause is OpenCV.

How can I downsize my exe file??

Thanks!

---

python 3.4.3

pyinstaller 3.0

Comment: I guess `VideoCapture` itself is large.

Comment: maybe your converter links the opencv static and puts them into your exe.